# List influxdb series by filtering on series name

Tags: influxdb

I am using influxdb in conjunction with grafana.  As part of a grafana query, I'd like to select influx series' that are part of a set that I know already.  If my series are named 'a', 'b', and 'c', I'd like a "show series"-like command that will return eg. 'a', 'b'.  Is this possible with influx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correct but you can select multiple Series with:

```
select * from a, b;
```

if your questions is about how you can solve this in grafana, you can simply create a graph with two query's. One which selects **a** and one which selects **b**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Found this commit to influxdb:
https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/pull/4501

Since you mentioned Grafana, I assume you want the measurements in a graphite format? In that case this syntax with regex seems to work:

```
SHOW MEASUREMENTS WITH MEASUREMENT =~ /cpu.*/
```

Would show all series related to %cpu%

However a regex on the SHOW SERIES query does not work (influxDB 1.3.3) even though it was indicated here https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/613